# Exception handling in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I am trying to insert a note into a table xyz. I get an error. There is another column `noteid` (identity) which is not specified in the list of columns, but value is being entered in values which I did on purpose.

I added 4 values to make the insert fail and check. When it succeeds, I am getting message from if statements as success, but when it fails, I am not getting any message from else statements.

Please point out my mistake, what did I do wrong ?

```
DECLARE @errornumbetr tinyint

BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO [dbo].xyz ([MemberID], [UserID], [Added])
VALUES (1, '0005135', 'USER', GETDATE())
       
SET @errornumber = @@ERROR

IF (@errornumber = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Success! Inserted note'
    COMMIT TRAN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Couldn''t insert note'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
GO
```

Comment: you have two variables `@errornumbetr` and `@errornumber` - one problem. Another is that you are inserting four values when your column list only has three values. Lot's of problems here. Fix up the code so that your actual problem is clear.

Comment: Also by the way testing error numbers is somewhat dated. Using try-catch would probably be better overall.

Comment: As a note, your `PRINT` command will *never* be entered, even if you had a `TRY...CATCH`. Having a statement that tries to `INSERT` more columns than defined in the `INSERT` clause will generate a compilation error; the *entire batch* will never be run.

Comment: Obligatory link to Erland Sommerskog's Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server: https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of things here:

Providing an example of the object you're working with would be helpful. This allows us to see what problems may be occurring due to that (data types and the like).

You can easily provide this example like this:

```
DECLARE @xyz TABLE (MemberID INT, UserID INT, Added DATETIME)
```

Next when using transactions it's a good idea to NAME them:

```
BEGIN TRAN InsertIntoXYZ
```

You can then reference them by this name when you need to.

The error you're causing to happen is a parsing problem, your query won't actually attempt to execute, because the engine can see it's wrong before anything actually happens.

We can cause other errors that will attempt to execute to trigger your condition though, such as inserting the wrong data type into a column.

Finally, TRY/CATCH is the proper way to handle this. Using this will also make available a number of other values which can provide you with more [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Here is how I would write (and test) this:

```
DECLARE @xyz TABLE (MemberID INT, UserID INT, Added DATETIME)

BEGIN TRAN InsertIntoXYZ
BEGIN TRY
 INSERT INTO @xyz (MemberID, UserID, Added) VALUES
 (1+'A', '0005135', GETDATE())
 PRINT 'Success!!  Inserted note'
 COMMIT TRAN InsertIntoXYZ
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 PRINT 'Couldn''t insert note: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
 ROLLBACK TRAN InsertIntoXYZ
END CATCH
```

```
(0 rows affected)
Couldn't insert note: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.
```

Comment: In truth, `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` would likely be better here; then you don't even need the `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: @Larnu could be a good use for it, yeah, but there may be more work to do outside of the block. XACT_ABORT: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjKwPigxJz7AhVVrYkEHaZECBkQFnoECBIQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsql%2Ft-sql%2Fstatements%2Fset-xact-abort-transact-sql%23%3A~%3Atext%3DPrevious%2520versions%2520documentation.-%2CRemarks%2Cand%2520the%2520transaction%2520continues%2520processing.&usg=AOvVaw37odTju-BM1WG_B01dB5WR

Comment: I'm not sure of your point (or the large google link), Patrick.

Comment: The link was for anyone interested in reading about XACT_ABORT. (the google link points right to the appropriate section on the page). 
My point was perhaps we don't want to terminate and rollback the entire statement because we encountered an error. If that's the desired outcome then sure, XACT_ABORT is a good way to go.

Comment: *"My point was perhaps we don't want to terminate and rollback the entire statement because we encountered an error."* Yet that is what will happen in the above too, due to the transaction and the `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH`. With a single `INSERT`, there's actually no need for the transaction at all.

Comment: *"The link was for anyone interested in reading about XACT_ABORT"* Linking straight to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) seems like a better choice then, rather than a Google Redirect; hence my confusion.

Comment: @Larnu If you wanted to do further work inside the batch, and did not use TRY/CATCH here you would terminate the entire batch and not execute anything further.
Handling the error properly gives more control over the flow.
The link goes go directly to the documentation, with the explanation highlighted...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249403/discussion-between-patrick-hurst-and-larnu).

Comment: I will admit that the vote is not mine here. I don't think this is the "best" way, but it'll still work, and I don't dispute that.